# React Chrome Extension - How to pass data to React component from background.js

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I am creating a chrome extension which will inject something into DOM of any webpage.
I have following directories in my project structure

1. extension
2. react-app

My manifest.json looks like this

```
{
    "name": "My Chrome Extension",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "content_scripts": [
        {
          "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
          "js": [
            "content.js"
          ]
        }
      ],
      "background": {
        "service_worker": "./background.js"
      },
      "action": {
        "default_popup":"popup.html"
      },
  }
```

content.js is minified bundle file of react-app where I have all my components which I want to inject into webpages.

From background.js I am calling the APIs to fetch data. and this data I want to pass to my react components.

How can I do that?

Comment: Use [chrome messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging).

Comment: I tried, but seems like I can't use chrome inside my react component

Comment: Show your code and describe the problem in more detail. Note that if your IDE complains about `chrome` you just need to suppress the warning or install [chrome-types](https://www.npmjs.com/package/chrome-types).

Comment: @Aftab What's the error you are getting when you try to use chrome.messaging API?

Comment: it got resolved after installing chrome-types

Comment: I did not understand what your saying. I already have [background.js](https://github.com/kasir-barati/open-ai-summaries/blob/11960c9391338504b85fa06cde04a7bd04e7ceb7/apps/chrome/public/background.js) but IDK how to listen to it [here](https://github.com/kasir-barati/open-ai-summaries/blob/11960c9391338504b85fa06cde04a7bd04e7ceb7/apps/chrome/src/components/CreateSummary/CreateSummary.component.tsx). Any idea?